# Access VBA vertical scroll bar

Tags: user-interface, ms-access, vba

I am building a quite complex form in Access. I would like to have a vertical scroll bar control that will scroll through a list of pictures. What I want the scroll bar to actually do is change the pictures in the picture control when it is scrolled.

Is there a way to insert a vertical scroll bar into an Access form where the scroll events can be automated?

I would rather not get into a discussion defending my UI, as it is pretty complex.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're asking to mis-use a UI component. There is no way to get a scrollbar in Access except by having some scrollable content. You might be able to do it with a continuous subform and bind that to your image control, but there is no way to make the scollbar change the current record. This is just a bad idea, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an Active X Scroll bar is available on your system, you can use that. It should have values that you can use VBA to compare to determine movement (up or down) and based on that, change the picture.

Comment: Non-native ActiveX controls are almost never a good idea in an Access app.

Comment: I have used ActiveX controls in projects in the past and that may be my only solution in this situation. The problem I had was ensuring that the control was available on the clients system. Is there a simple way to feel confident that a certain MS ActiveX control will be available on the target systems(s)?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Would you mind elaborating a bit more as to why non-ActiveX controls aren't a good idea?

Comment: Only some non-native ActiveX controls are compatible with Access. Secondly, when you introduce an outside dependency into your app, you're making it more fragile. That is, installing it is much more likely to break. But to me, a scrollbar is not the most "intuitive" UI for navigating a slideshow, so I don't think you even need to get into the ActiveX issue.

Answer (score 1):

A scrollbar is never going to work. I'd suggest previous/next command buttons as the absolutely simplest solution to the problem, as well as being a UI that is quite familiar to anyone who has ever used any kind of slideshow anywhere.

Comment: You can see an example of such at http://granitefleet.com/ScreenShots/screen_MainMenu.htm

Comment: Just about every slideshow on the Internet uses < and > buttons, so I can't imagine that wouldn't be the most intuitive interface. I don't know what would be more intuitive about a scrollbar -- to me it's much less clear, not to mention the fact that there are no hooks are vents to make it move the current record.

Answer (score 0):

In access 2010, or 2007, you can use the new image control. You can point to a file on hard disk. You don't need any code, and you can thus display icons, or graphics for each row, and do so without any code:

[image]

And, you can also use the attachment column. And again, display pictures in continues forms without code. Here is a another screen:

[image]

So, we don't need any 3rd party controls here.

Comment: Albert, I don't see how this answers the question, which is about the UI control for navigating between images, not about what control to use for displaying them. Your examples both use continuous forms (I'm guessing), which displays more than one image, where the original question describes a single form with a single image control, and some method for swapping the image in and out of that control. I just don't see how your answer addresses the actual question asked.